# Can we estimate the profuct $(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ldots(1+x_n)$ by the term $x_1\ldots x_n$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ be postive integers with $x_i\ge 2(1\le i\le n)$. Can we have the following inequality:
$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_n)\le f(n)x_1\cdots x_n,$$
where $f(n)$ is a term  dependent on $n$ and I hope it is increasing in Polynomials or lower order. Does anyone can do it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint can be written

$$\left(\frac1{x_1}+1\right)\left(\frac1{x_2}+1\right)\cdots\left(\frac1{x_n}+1\right)\le\left(\frac32\right)^n$$ and this is tight.

Comment: This means that $f(n)$ is exponential growth, which is two fast and  I need it grows slower than exponential growth

Comment: @ljjpfx: it is tight, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You mean $(\frac{3}{2})^n$ is the best upper bound and it is cannot be smaller, right?

Comment: @exactly. For $x_n\ge M$, any $M$, it remains exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Left product create $2^n$ members, which all are $\geqslant 2$ and their maximum is $x_1\cdots x_n$.

Comment: Than you @zkutch. You mean $f(n)=2^n$. This is a directly estimate. But it is too rough and $f(n)$  is exponential growth, too fast.

Comment: @ljjpfx. You are welcome. As you see from Yves Daoust's answer anyway it will be exponential with base $>1$. This is because of conditions $x_i \geqslant 2$ - can you elaborate some more good conditions?

Comment: Yes. You and Yves are right. My requiretment is not reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use trigonometry  because :
$$1+\tan^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$
So you can put : $$1+x_i=1+\tan^2(y_i)$$

Comment: Thank you @Biggus Dickus Python